# I would like the MIN - MAX from each month and every site_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First Table: site_map_pae

```
id |  site_id   | site_name |  off_id
1    213140951       Med         3
2    213140952     Vedmed        3
```

Second Table: electric

```
id |        timeIn           | energy  |  site_id
1     2022-07-07 07:20:35        150     213140951
2     2022-07-07 10:46:23        155     213140952
3     2022-07-09 18:37:23        160     213140951
4     2022-08-01 14:46:23        170     213140951
5     2022-08-03 19:46:23        180     213140952
6     2022-08-06 20:46:23        190     213140952
7     2022-08-09 13:37:23        200     213140951
```

*****the results that I would like to achieved is like this.**

```
id |        timeIn           | result_energy 
1     2022-07-09 18:37:23          10          
2     2022-08-09 13:37:23          40
```

**this is my query. I would like SQL Inner join via off_id = "3" on table site_map_pae.**
`

```
SELECT Max(DISTINCT energy)-MIN(DISTINCT energy) as result_energy, max(timeIn) as timeIn
FROM Electric.site_map_pae AS t1
INNER JOIN Electric.electric AS t2
ON t1.site_id = t2.site_id
WHERE t1.off_id = "3"
AND t2.timeIn BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and '2022-12-31 23:59:59'
```

`

my results:

```
     id |  result_energy |      timeIn
      1      50.00         2022-08-09 13:37:23
```

Comment: What's your question about this? How is this problem related to PHP?

Comment: Does https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48203/how-to-get-max-and-min-in-group-by-query help?

Comment: For the fastest, best support, provide a ready-to-use db-fiddle.com demo link.

Answer (score 1):

You have no grouping in your query so it just shows 1 row.

Since you want it for each month, each site_id then you need to group by month and site_id.

`MONTH(timeIn)` will get the month from the timeIn field.

```
SELECT Max(DISTINCT energy)-MIN(DISTINCT energy) as result_energy,MONTH(timeIn) as timeIn_month, t1.site_id
FROM Electric.site_map_pae AS t1
INNER JOIN Electric.electric AS t2
ON t1.site_id = t2.site_id
WHERE t1.off_id = "3"
AND t2.timeIn BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and '2022-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY MONTH(timeIn), t1.site_id
```

Something like this, hope it helps.

Comment: You'd need the year as well in GROUP BY

Comment: @HonkderHase No since he has: `AND t2.timeIn BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and '2022-12-31 23:59:59'` in where clause

Comment: Ok, you're right :)